# OnMouseOver In Unity

Tags: c#, triggers, unity-game-engine, onmouseover

quick question I got this script here to show the name of an Item you collect. These names are made public so I can change them within the item list. What I want to do Is to walk into an item and hover my mouse over the item so it can display the name of the item in the middle of the screen. I don't know if I should use a trigger, or a GUILayout or however. Please Help and thanks. Here is the Script: **UPDATED**

```
public class RayCasting : MonoBehaviour
{
public float pickupDistance;
public List<Item> items;
//public List<Keybutton> buttons;

#region Unity
void Start ()
{
    Screen.lockCursor = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++) {
        Item temp = items[i];
        int randomIndex = Random.Range(i, items.Count);
        items[i] = items[randomIndex];
        items[randomIndex] = temp;
    }
}
void Update ()
{
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = new Ray (transform.position, transform.forward);
            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, pickupDistance)) {
                    foreach (Item item in items) {

                            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
                                    if (item.gameObject.Equals (hit.collider.gameObject)) {
                                            numItemsCollected++;
                                            item.Collect ();
                                            break;
                                    }

                            }
                    }
            }
    }

void OnGUI()
{

    GUI.backgroundColor = Color.blue;
    GUI.Box(new Rect(120,390,170,250),"Text Message");
    GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(132,432,100,170));
    {
        GUILayout.BeginVertical();
        {
    if (numItemsCollected < items.Count)
    {
        foreach (Item item in items)

                    GUILayout.Label(string.Format("[{0}] {1}", item.Collected ? "" + item.password: " ", item.name ));

    }
    else
    {
    foreach (Item item in items)

                    GUILayout.Label(string.Format("[{0}] {1}", item.Collected ? "" + item.password: " ", item.name ));          
                //GUILayout.Label("Take code to KeyPad");
    }
        }
        GUILayout.EndVertical();
}
    GUILayout.EndArea();

    //Enter Code to unlock doors.

                    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (250, 830, 100, 50), "Enter Code"))
                    if (numItemsCollected > items.Count) {              
                            Debug.Log ("Entering Code");
                }
}

#endregion

#region Private
private int numItemsCollected;
#endregion
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Item
{
public string name;
//public GUIText textObject;
public GameObject gameObject;
public float guiDelay = 0.1f;

private float lastHoverTime = -99.0f;
public int password;

public bool Collected { get; private set; }



public void Collect()
{
    Collected = true;
    //gameObject.SetActive(false);
}

public void passwordNumber()
{
    password = 0;
    Collected = true;
    gameObject.SetActive(false);
}

void OnMouseEnter ()
{
    lastHoverTime = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;
}

void OnGUI(){
            if (lastHoverTime + guiDelay > Time.timeSinceLevelLoad) {
                    GUI.Box (new Rect (300, 300, 170, 250), name);
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Attach following script to every item. It will show `QUI.Box` when mouse hovers the item. Just change the size of the `QUI.Box` and set the `message` to suitable values.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HoverGUI : MonoBehaviour {

    public string message = "Foo Bar";
    public float guiDelay = 0.1f;

    private float lastHoverTime = -99.0f;
    void OnMouseOver() {
        lastHoverTime = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;
    }

    void OnGUI(){
        if(lastHoverTime + guiDelay > Time.timeSinceLevelLoad){
            GUI.Box(new Rect(0,0,170,250),message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I suppose to add any trigger events to this?

Comment: I thought that your problem was that you were not able to display GUI elements onMouseOver. With my script example that works, no any extra triggers or anything needed. You can easily modify it to your needs. It is hard to write complete code since I don't have the scene.

Comment: Oh I see I tried to modify it in my way but I think I failed at it lol. But I was wondering if I can subsitute the string message to string name. The string name has built in names already but its in my class Raycasting. Should I just call the string name from the raycasting to the class HoverGui?

Comment: I put the entire code on here so you can see where Im coming from. I inserted your code with my Item Class but I dont know if I may need to also add this within my RayCasting code. Hopefully this Helps

Comment: If you have Raycasting script attached to every item, you can also add the two functions, `lastHoverTime` and `quiDelay` to Raycasting script. Then you can substitute `message` with `name`. Or if Raycasting is at another gameObject you need to find that gameObject `GameObject.Find` and get the component `.GetComponent<Raycasting>()` and use its value instead of the `message`.

Comment: If you want to see the text as long as the mouse is on top of the item use `OnMouseOver` like I did. Not `OnMouseEnter` which is only called at the beginning of the hover.